# Get updated balance from multiple wallet files using the CLI Monero wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, balance

Is there a command to output my wallet balance and unlocked balance from my main monero address using the command line Monero wallet? And what if I wanted to get the balance of my subaddresses?

I want to get it without interaction as this would be used in a script, which means the wallets won't have a password or a simple password if it's mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using `monero-wallet-cli` you can run the command `balance detail`, which will show you your wallets balance and each balance received at each subaddress.

Typically for non-interactive usage you'd use `monero-wallet-rpc`, for which there is an equivalent method [get_balance](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance), which gives you  result in something more machine readable (e.g. JSON).

You can also use the `monero-wallet-cli` non-interactively like:

```
monero-wallet-cli --testnet --wallet-file testnet-wallet --password 'yourpassword' balance detail
```

Comment: is there a way to output the data in a json format?

Comment: also where can i find all the options for the cli and rpc commands like **balance detail**?

Comment: actually I just did the command you mentioned on a new wallet i created and funded it with some coins. the balance doesn't update until I do a "refresh", but it hits me with a password prompt, which isn't going to work for me. Is there a way to get an updated balance when passing in the **balance detail** or even **show_transfers in** command?

Comment: "is there a way to output the data in a json format?" <- for that, use the monero-wallet-rpc

Comment: "also where can i find all the options for the cli and rpc commands like balance detail?" <- type help

Comment: "actually I just did the command you mentioned on a new wallet" <- the commands above assume you are operating on a synced/refreshed wallet.

Comment: "but it hits me with a password prompt" <- to prevent the wallet from asking passwords run `set ask-password = 0`

Comment: is there a way to do a refresh and do a check for "show_transfer in" without making it 2 separate commands?

Comment: If you were using the RPC (which sounds like you should be, w/out not knowing your trying to build), and left it running, you wouldn't need the refresh at all. If your going to use the cli, no, you will have to do the refresh first (if it's not already up-to-date).